# Counting most registrations in past 9 days

Tags: mysql

I have above database with data

How can I  select country which has the most registrations from the past 9 days

```
ID NAME COUNTRY CREATED
1  JEF  UK      2019-05-19 10:10:40
2  TRO  USA     2019-05-10 15:10:30
3  BTI  UK      2019-05-05 12:10:20
4  NGU  CA      2019-05-10 14:10:10
```

here is my query

```
select country from user group by country order by count(*) desc and created > now() - interval 9 day
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY... ORDER BY...`

Comment: That's right, the `and` should be removed and the condition should be in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, the `WHERE` clause condition was added in the `ORDER BY`. Moving the `created > now() - interval 9 day` to the `WHERE` clause will work.

The query will be:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as CountryCount 
FROM `user` 
WHERE created > now() - interval 9 day
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

To get the country which has highest registration in the past 9 days, use
`ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1`, the query will be:

```
SELECT country
FROM `user` 
WHERE created > now() - interval 9 day
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY count(*) desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this just counts but dont bring the country name. i want country name

Comment: @JackPato If the `country` is in the `SELECT`, it should return the `country name`

Comment: @JackPato Can you please add some more sample data and expected result?

Comment: your answer is not working out. i cant add more sample data. because you can read wat i posted and sample query and db. i just need only to get country name which has the highest registrars in pest 9 days

Comment: @JackPato I hope you are looking for `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1`, plese check my updated answer